# OpenGL ES multiple objects not being rendered

Tags: android, object, opengl-es, rendering

I am doing the following to render multiple balls move around the screen but only 1 ball is seen to appear and function. I don't know why the rest (count-1) balls are not being drawn

```
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
             gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   
             gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glClientActiveTexture(DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
             gl.glLoadIdentity();
             for(int i=0;i<mParticleSystem.getParticleCount();i++){
                gl.glPushMatrix();
                      gl.glTranslatef(mParticleSystem.getPosX(i), mParticleSystem.getPosY(i), -3.0f);
                      gl.glScalef(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
                      gl.glColor4f(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1);
                      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);   
                      mParticleSystem.getBall(i).draw(gl);
                gl.glPopMatrix();

             }


        }
```

**EDIT** My void draw(GL10 gl) method

```
    public void draw(GL10 gl){

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//  gl.glTranslatef(0.2f, 0.2f, -3.0f);
//  gl.glScalef(size, size, 1.0f);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

 }
```

I couldnt take the snapshot on my Samsung Phone but here is the emulator screenshot. In reality, the ball moves around with change in orientation and acceleration and keeps changing color randomly (due to r.nextFLoat()) . However, the other 35 balls arent even being rendered as you can see. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you write the  mParticleSystem.getBall(i).draw(gl) code ?,  are you disabling anything in it?

Comment: well i meant the MyGLBall.draw(GL10 gl) method  in your MyGLBall class

Comment: @SteveL Oh I see. Updated my answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this is called gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);, the second time the loop comes back should have gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); otherwise nothing else will be drawn.

I bet you have gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); in you onsurfacecreated(). This means is only called once. While gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); is being called infinitely.

Comment: Look a little closer, he enables it the line before glDrawElements.